# Using PhantomJS on Windows Server 2008 results in JSON ValueError

Tags: json, phantomjs, headless-browser

I'm attempting to move some existing code for Selenium/Headless testing over to a machine which is running Windows Server 2008 R2. When even running the most basic PhantomJS code

```
from selenium import webdriver
phantomJSPath = "D:\phantomjs.exe"
desiredCap = {"platform": "ANY", "browserName": "phantomjs", "version": "",     "javascriptEnabled": True}
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomJSPath, port=0,     desired_capabilities=desiredCap)
```

I get an error that results in "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

The exact same code works fine on my Linux and Windows 7 machine, but not this. Any idea of what could be the issue?

Comment: Does it work with the default capabilities?

Comment: It does not, the code above is what I used to isolate the JSON just in case that was that issue.

Comment: in your example, looks like `desiredCap` is not a valid JSON  `"javascriptEnabled": True` should be true with lowercase